# Writing a cache implementation for storing the responses of a REST call

Tags: rest, caching, redis, memcached, lru

I am trying to write an lru cache implementation for storing the responses from REST call.

1)Defining my own class and functions or

2)Using libraries like cachetools, functools, memcache or

3)Using Redis projects

Which would be better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Caches are Hard. Unless it's for a play project or a learning exercise, don't write your own. Use something written by somebody who has spent a long time thinking hard about caches.

As far as which one, we have nowhere near enough information to make that decision for you. Look at the available features and see how they map to your requirements.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the reply.